# WORD - Find and replace text via Text in quotation marks

Tags: vba, ms-word

How Can I  find and trim spaces between quotation text?

for example: if the word contains the following string:
**I say to him ' why should I?   ' he answers...**
It will replace:
**I say to him 'why should I?' he answers...**

I know that the regular expression to find text in the quotation is:(\'*?\')  but from here I could not progress.

Any help will be highly appreciated
Asi

Comment: I see you tagged three languages. Can you show us how far you got with your code in each language? Also: Which language would you prefer to use?

Comment: FWIW don't try to use regular expressions in Word; use Word's built-in FIND functionality, with *wildcards*. These are similar to RegEx, but not identical. Also, the scope of this question is "too broad" according to Stack Overflow guidelines (see the [help]). There should be only ONE question topic per question - you ask at least two. Please use the [edit] link to add the code you've tried that isn't working - Stack Overflow is not a free coding service...

Comment: Make sure you tag things properly, I have edited your question to remove vb.net and vbscript as they are no correct. You also need to post a copy of what you have done thus far, Stack Overflow is not a code writing sweatshop, it's a repository of information for learning and building on. We don't write your code for you, we teach you how to fix it for yourself so you are better armed next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a VBA solution, try:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Rng As Range, Rslt
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[‘'][!^13^l^t]@['’]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Select
    Set Rng = .Duplicate
    With Rng
      .Start = .Start + 1
      .End = .End - 1
      If .Text <> Trim(.Text) Then
        Rslt = MsgBox("Trim this instance?", vbYesNoCancel)
        If Rslt = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
        If Rslt = vbYes Then
          Do While .Characters.Last = " "
            .Characters.Last = vbNullString
          Loop
          Do While .Characters.First = " "
            .Characters.First = vbNullString
          Loop
        End If
      End If
    End With
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** If the strings don't have any formatting applied, you could reduce:

```
  Do While .Characters.Last = " "
    .Characters.Last = vbNullString
  Loop
  Do While .Characters.First = " "
    .Characters.First = vbNullString
  Loop
```

to:

```
  .Text = Trim(.Text)
```

To work with just a selected range, change:

```
Dim Rng As Range, Rslt
With ActiveDocument.Range
```

to:

```
Dim Rng As Range, RngSel As Range, Rslt
With Selection.Range
  Set RngSel = .Duplicate
```

and insert:

```
    If .InRange(RngSel) = False Then Exit Sub
```

before:

```
    .Select
```

Comment: Thank you !  May I ask if I want it to work only on the selection text, what should I do ? (and not on the entire doc)

Comment: @AsiB See edited answer. **Note:** it would have been helpful had you stated your full requirements from the outset.